# How to silently uninstall Visio remotely

Tags: powershell, uninstall, microsoft-visio

I have to remove Microsoft Visio silentlyy from a lot computer. I tried Uninstall-Package and wmic commands, via PsExec, seems working but not uninstalling, still there. It is for Visio 2016 and Visio 2019. Does uninstall string work if I get? But I have to force uninstall silently, its important.

The uninstall string: `"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE15\Office Setup Controller\setup.exe" /uninstall VISPRO /dll OSETUP.DLL MsiExec.exe /X{90150000-0051-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE} MsiExec.exe /X{90150000-0054-0409-1000-0000000FF1CE}`

```
'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*',
'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*',
'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ItemProperty $_ | Where-Object {
        $_.DisplayName -like '*Visio*'
    } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'UninstallString'
}

Write-Host $Command
```

Comment: I think you need `Start-Process msiexec "/X {90150000-0054-0409-1000-0000000FF1CE}" -Wait;`. You can try wrapping that in an `Invoke-Command -ComputerName Machinexyz -ScriptBlock {Start-Process msiexec "/X {90150000-0054-0409-1000-0000000FF1CE}" -Wait}` that way too for remote uninstall potentially.

Comment: I think its waiting forever.

Comment: I know if can take some times sometimes depending on various environment and system variables. If it continues to hang, perhaps kill it with `taskkill` which can be run remotely as well. I typically work out the commands from a machine via RDP, physical access, then turn around and test those confirmed commands via remote from the same machine (reinstall) or another. Then once I confirm it works on one via the commands locally, one via the remote commands, I then run in the masses. I usually have to do these things with hundreds of machines in my case though; not sure how large you scale.

Comment: And when you test, try it without the `-wait` and perhaps with it too both. Try it remotely on the remote machine while you are RDP'd into it but run the remote command from another machine, this way you should see what the end-user may see when they are logged in and the command runs. It might take some tweaking, I gave you the basics but I have to fine-tune accordingly all the time but that's usually only the trivial to figure out. Let me know how it goes, and good luck!!

Comment: Here is a screen snip of another way I've done this with Office 2021 LTSC using PowerShell and the XML configuration file. https://i.imgur.com/U7OlYiY.png. The products installed which you want to remove are listed in the config file then the PowerShell uninstall logic is run to remove those is Outlook.exe exists. This was an old script I had to run ad-hoc for some reason, so it was still laying around. I did it that way once upon a time but should work similarly with M365. I asked out the UNC paths but I assume you get the picture. You install configuration may matter here though too.