# Cmd uninstall string not working

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office, cmd.exe, uninstall

I have to remove a software from several computers with remotely.  Uninstall-Package and `wmic` commands seems working but not working, the software still there.

I thought I can uninstall with uninstall string but its not working too. I have to remove silently on PsExec or PS Remoting.

The uninstall string:

```
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE15\Office Setup Controller\setup.exe" /uninstall VISPRO /dll OSETUP.DLL MsiExec.exe /X{90150000-0051-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE} MsiExec.exe /X{90150000-0054-0409-1000-0000000FF1CE}
```

Comment: This seems to be an extension of [How to silently uninstall Visio remotely](https://superuser.com/questions/1813072/how-to-silently-uninstall-visio-remotely)